# What verb goes with "coup"?

Tags: word-request, verbs

> The coup was ______ in this country by the United States.
>
> It was indeed United States that ______ the coup in this country.
>
> If the problems take a turn to the worse, then the army would ______ a
>   coup.

I want a verb for the blanks. In the above contexts, the United States or the army are meant to be the *main* *agency* in doing the coup.

I thought about **run/ran** and **set**. Are these idiomatic suggestions? Any better suggestions?

Comment: Did the US actually *carry out* (**stage**, **execute**), or did they just "pull the strings" by manipulating others behind the scenes (**sponsor**, **orchestrate**)?

Comment: Please be more clear about what kind of situation you're asking about, because the accepted answer doesn't seem to suit the examples given in the question. Any word which can truly fill in any of the blanks given in the question can't mean that the United States actually sent people in to another country to overthrow the governing powers. That would be more like an invasion, not a coup. I'm not saying that coups can't be materially supported, provoked, sponsored, or otherwise influenced by a foreign power, but a coup is, by definition, inherently a domestic event.

Comment: @Beanluc Question edited. When they plan the coup, and support it in all ways, including financially, then I believe they can be taken as the main agency behind it, and so "stage" seems to be the best option.

Comment: @Beanluc they are the main agency involved, indeed the only organizer of the coup. So "stage" seems to be the best option. No?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You *stage* a coup, like the documentary [How to Stage a Coup](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7149296/).

> 2. to produce or cause to happen for public view or public effect
>      *// stage a track meet
>
>      // stage a hunger strike*

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stage))

In cases like this, an [NGram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+a+coup&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) is often helpful. (The `*` basically means "find the words most used at that position" and `_VERB` specifies you're only looking for verbs.) Here, we can see that *stage* is the most commonly used verb.

Of course, you do need to pay attention to what the words actually mean; other top hits like *plan* and *attempt* mean something else.

Comment: I didn't know about the search feature of NGram, that's cool. I wonder why the present tense "stage" has been declining recently.

Comment: @Barmar: The present tense seems to have been most popular during the Cold War. Obviously, that's not conclusive evidence of anything, but it does seem rather congruous to me.

Comment: This depends heavily on the context. In fact, while this would seem to be the right answer for example 3, it doesn't seem to be for the other two answers (because a coup is staged by a faction within a country, another country can't stage a coup, though it can definitely orchestrate one)

Answer (score 12):

While the term *stage* in Glorfindel's answer is widely applicable, it implies primarily the planning and preparation for a coup and not *necessarily* success. [Less common but used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+a+coup%2Cexecute*+a+coup&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3) to refer specifically to the actions involved to carry out the plan is *execute a coup*, which does imply success.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/execute):

> 1. to carry out fully : put completely into effect
>      *// execute a command*

In the case of your example, it's possible that a coup might be *staged* by the United States but *executed* by some local organization.

Comment: I've seen many synonyms of this, too: `perform`, `pull off` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to *orchestrate a coup*.

> **or‧ches‧trate** */ˈɔːkəstreɪt $ ˈɔːr-/* verb [transitive]
>
> 1. *(written)* to organize an important event or a complicated plan, especially secretly
>
> Example: *The riots were orchestrated by anti-government forces.*

*(Source: [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/orchestrate))*

Comment: This. Foreign powers don't "execute" or "stage" coups, though they might sponsor domestic actors who are the ones who actually do so, and they might even supply agents on the ground at varying levels of deniability. A regime change perpetrated directly by the foreign actors of a foreign power isn't a coup, it's an invasion.

Comment: @Beanluc In that case, what is the best verb for such context in your view?

Comment: @Sasan "this", as in, this answer.

Answer (score 5):

"Mount" is an alternative to "stage"

> stage/lead/mount a coup
>   [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/coup)
>
> stage/mount/launch a coup
>   [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/coup)
>
> to stage/mount a coup
>   [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries: English](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/coup)

It is considerably less common on [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mount+a+coup%2Cstage+a+coup%2Cmounted+a+coup%2Cstaged+a+coup&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmount%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstage%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmounted%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaged%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmount%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstage%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmounted%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaged%20a%20coup%3B%2Cc0) though.

Answer (score 3):

What word to use there depends on what you want to say. The term "stage" implies that the entity in question actually performed the coup. For a outside party that has less of a direct role, there's "instigate"

> instigate 
>   : to goad or urge forward : PROVOKE

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instigate

or "back"

> : to support by material or moral assistance
>   backing a candidate for governor
>   —often used with up
>   back up a friend in a fight

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back

Answer (score 1):

I believe coups are *engineered*.

Comment: Please add sources to your answer, so it can be a good reference/source for learners. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Foment** - "instigate or stir up (an undesirable or violent sentiment or course of action)."

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your intended exact meaning, you could use "precipitate," "catalyze," or "encourage."